# WCF request throttling

Tags: c#, wcf, request, throttling

I'm using a third party .NET 4 WCF service that is added to my solution as a Service Reference. Is there a way to configure requests so that my service isn't Ddos:ing the third party service?

I'm aware of `ServiceThrottling` where the following parameters can be controlled:

```
- MaxConcurrentCalls
- MaxConcurrentSessions
- MaxConcurrentInstances
```

My application is single threaded so the above parameters will have no impact.

I would like to limit number requests per time period. Maybe by making a pause between each request. I could obviously write an adapter for the service and handle this myself, but the third party service contains ~200 methods so it would require lots of code.

Is it possible to throttle the requests this way *by configuration*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is already a couply of weeks old, so I do not know if you still need it. At least it is worth a try... Also, please correct me if I misunderstood your scenario.

As far as I understood, you want to restrict your own service to only call the third-party service one-request-after-another. I am not aware of a configurable solution for this. But, as you stated that it is possible for you to implement your own solution, I would suggest a different approach.

You might put your requests into a **queue** and then process one queue entry at a time.
This could be implemented in a variaty of ways, depending on the environment you have to work with.

there are two solution that come to my mind.

A simple approach might be to use an in-memory queue within your own service that calls the third party once per entry and use some kind of [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). But this might need some careful thought to avoid ugly deadlocks.

The more complex, but possibly better scalable solution: 
You can [configure your service](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/02/28/wcf-and-msmq.aspx) to write into a Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) infrastructure and [add another service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx) that processes those messages sequentially to the third party service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Nice answer! I've ended up implementing a wrapper for the 3rd party service. I didnt need to use a queue but I like the idea!